# Short vs Integer memory allocation

Tags: java, jvm

### Update

I gonna keep very big data structure `Map<Integer, Integer[]>` in memory, there is a risk of going OutOfMemory. *Will `Map<Integer, Short[]>` decrease a risk or there is no point of using `Short[]` instead of `Integer[]`?*

### Question

I'm wondering *why two arrays of the same size: `Short[]` and `Integer[]` consumes the same amount of memory?* Here is the output of code below:

```
Output:
Short primitives array size: 120 b
Int primitives array size: 216 b // It's ok, int takes 4 bytes, short takes 2 bytes
Short array size: 800 b
Int array size: 800 b // WHY?? Why Int[] takes the same amount of memory as Short[]
Short set size: 2960 b //There is no sense to use Set<Short> instead of Set<Integer> in Java, right?
Int set size: 2960 b
```

***MemoryTest.java***

```
private final static Integer MAX_VALUE = 1000;
private final static Integer AVERAGE_COLLECTION_LENGTH = 50;
private final static Random rand = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Short[] shortArray = genRandomArrayOfShort();
    Integer[] intArray = genRandomArrayOfInt();
    Set<Short> shortSet = genRandomSetOfShort();
    Set<Integer> intSet = genRandomSetOfInt();
    System.out.println("Short primitives array size: " + RamUsageEstimator.sizeOfAll(new short[AVERAGE_COLLECTION_LENGTH]) + " b");
    System.out.println("Int primitives array size: " + RamUsageEstimator.sizeOfAll(new int[AVERAGE_COLLECTION_LENGTH]) + " b");
    System.out.println("Short array size: " +  RamUsageEstimator.sizeOfAll(shortArray) + " b");
    System.out.println("Int array size: " + RamUsageEstimator.sizeOfAll(intArray) + " b");
    System.out.println("Short set size: " +  RamUsageEstimator.sizeOfAll(shortSet) + " b");
    System.out.println("Int set size: " +  RamUsageEstimator.sizeOfAll(intSet) + " b");
}

private static Set<Short> genRandomSetOfShort() {
    return Sets.newHashSet(genRandomArrayOfShort());
}

private static Set<Integer> genRandomSetOfInt() {
    return Sets.newHashSet(genRandomArrayOfInt());
}

private static Short[] genRandomArrayOfShort() {
    Short[] array = new Short[AVERAGE_COLLECTION_LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < AVERAGE_COLLECTION_LENGTH; i++) {
        array[i] = (short) rand.nextInt(MAX_VALUE);
    }
    return array;
}

private static Integer[] genRandomArrayOfInt() {
    Integer[] array = new Integer[AVERAGE_COLLECTION_LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < AVERAGE_COLLECTION_LENGTH; i++) {
        array[i] = rand.nextInt(MAX_VALUE);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Where [`RamUsageEstimator` lib](https://github.com/dweiss/java-sizeof) could be included to your project with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.carrotsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-sizeof</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you also try the primitives `int[]` and `short[]`?

Comment: The arrays don't contain the actual `Short` and `Integer` data. They contain pointers to `Short` and `Integer` objects. Pointers are the same size.

Comment: @glglgl sure, pls look at the output, the first and the second line. But as the final result I need smth like `Map<Integer, Short[]>` and wondering why I can't save some memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `Short` and `Integer` are both object and not primitive types. Object types are actually just stack references in size of 32/64 bit  that point to real values in memory heap. If you want to see real size difference, use `short` and `int`.
Example:

```
short[] shortArray;
int[] intArray
```

Comment: but isn't heap a part of RAM? I just waant to keep very big data structure in memory, and trying to ding a way not to go OutOfMemory

Comment: It is better to use Map<Integer, Short[]>.
Your array of Interer and Short references are the same size, but data size they point to in heap part of RAM isn't the same.

Comment: @agrga so RamUsageEstimator doesn't take into account heap, right? So what it's estimating?  Is there any way to estimate a heap size?

Comment: Either that or implementation of Short and Integer in Java requires same amount of memory, I don't know that, you could read about it in documentation of RamUsageEstimator.sizeOfAll.

Answer (score 4):

All Object references have the same size in Java. What you see is the amount of memory required to hold the reference to the actual objects.

Imagine both arrays filled with `null`. Shouldn't they both require the same size?

**Update:** To reduce memory usage, you should use arrays of primitives and not wrapper types. So, using the standard JDK classes, the best you can do is probably using `Map<Integer, short[]>`.

You can read about how to calculate memory usage for your data in this [blog post](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml).

Comment: agree, but isn't value to which reference points saved also in RAM?

Comment: You can't fill a variable with null. You can only set it's pointer to null. It won't take up any memory

Comment: @volo the Integer object isn't just a wrapper around the int primitive, it contains additional methods